# mysql: grant command denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need help regarding mysql grant command.
I need to grant select command on a table to a user which is from different host.

`GRANT SELECT on db.table TO user@xx.xx.xxx AT password`
(xx.xx.xxx is ip address of other server and user is username at that server)

The above statement is giving me error:

> ## 1174 - Grant command denied to user

It is working fine in the localhost phpmyadmin. But when I do it in cpanel phpmyadmin it gives error.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, you simply don't have the **GRANT OPTION** privilege.

You might have grant privileges in localhost but you certainly don't on your cpanel (live server)

The **GRANT** statement grants privileges to MySQL user accounts. To use GRANT, you must.

- Have the GRANT OPTION privilege,
- And you must have the privileges that you are granting.

Also:

> The GRANT OPTION privilege enables users to give their privileges to
>   other users. Two users that have different privileges and with the
>   GRANT OPTION privilege are able to combine privileges.

As with most hosts, When they create your account, a mysql account/user is also automatically generated to go along with it, and its (usually) given a [database privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html). Therefore, the privileges they give you / that comes with your account are all you have. So if you are the admin of your account and you dont have the **grant option** privilege, you wont be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks for help. Is there any way from where I can achieve this. In my sql query I am selecting records from 2 databases and both databases are in different server. I guess there must be some way by which I can do this

Comment: On the other server, create a function (php or whichever) to grab the data you want, then acces that using `curl` http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php. But thats beyond this question, You can ask how to do that in another question.

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need the `AT password`

Here is the example from the MySQL docu:

`GRANT SELECT ON db2.invoice TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';`

The password should be handled at your `CREATE USER` statement.

Please try it this way. Does your own user which runs the `GRANT`-statement has the right to give rights? Is it an admin user?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need GRANT command to be enabled in my cpanel phpmyadmin
Yes I am the admin of the account but GRANT command is not there in the privilege

Comment: Well I don't get it. Just add a login for that user and map the database with the grant command to it? He should be fine and could query the table he needs. Or did I get it wrong. You just want to set some permissions, right?

Comment: My Problem is
In my mysql query I am selecting records from 2 databases and both database are in different server. One user has all the privileges because he is in the same server. The other user needs select permission for which I am unable to grant him through cpanel phpmyadmin

Comment: Why don't you just use the grant command I've given you in your MySQL Server? It's the easiest way. I won't use something like cpanel or whatever for this task?

Answer (score 0):

> > > Try This
> > >       Add skip-grant-tables in my.cnf file under the [mysqld] section or otherwise stop mysqld and start it with the --skip-grant-tables option.

```
Use mysql to connect to DB without password without -p

Then execute this:

UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Then execute: GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```